# bluemixでCMSなどでアップロードしたファイルを永続的に保存する方法

Tags: bluemix

先日からトライアル期間としてBluemixを利用し始めました。

OpenShift や Engine Yard では永続的なディスク領域があり、そこにシンボリックリンクを貼ることでコードをデプロイしてもファイルが消えてしまうのを防いでいました。

Bluemixではどのように対応すれば良いのかアドバイス頂けないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

IBM Bluemix VM (beta) の場合だと永続ディスクがあります (200Gbyte)。Cloud Foundry ランタイムを利用する場合には、バックエンド DB をサポートする CMS を利用するという方法があります。

例：
Camaleon CMS ( http://blog.cloudfoundry.gr.jp/2015/09/cf100apps-051-camaleon-cms.html )
Wonder CMS ( http://blog.cloudfoundry.gr.jp/2015/06/cf100apps-015-wondercms.html )

具体的に、どの CMS を検討されていますでしょうか？

Comment: 情報不足でした、アプリとして[Drupal](https://www.drupal.org)を使用します。

Comment: 英語で恐縮ですが、以下の文書が参考になるかもしれません。

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/02/17/deploy-drupal-application-ibm-bluemix/

バックエンドは MySQL のようです。Bluemix の MySQL server は Experimental なので、データ保全に課題がありますので、独自にたてるか（例： Softlayer VM上）、あるいは MySQL クラウドベンダーのサービスを利用することをお勧めします。なお、試験的に使うのであれば、Bluemix の MySQL でもOKかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。データベースについてはサードパーティのClearDBを使用する予定です。問題と考えているのは、画像ファイルなどのファイルです。

Comment: なるほど、個人的には試していませんが、以下の情報を見つけました。
https://www.drupal.org/project/openstack_storage
Drupalは、openstack swift ストレージと統合できるようですね。Bluemix には Swift ベースの Object Storage があるので、もしかしたら統合できるかもしれません。

 https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/object-storage/

以前、IBMの jStart チームが Wordpress で同様の問題を Object Storage を使って解決していました。
 https://github.com/ibmjstart/wp-bluemix-objectstorage
正確な回答になっておらず、申し訳ないですが、ご参考まで。